# sorting using the -k command

Tags: sort

I have a script that gets people to enter name, number and date in the format of YYYY/MM/DD which then appends to a file so it looks like:

```
Alex, 133454543, 1990/12/14
Tom, 234234235, 1992/10/09
```

I want to sort the file by the month and then day.
I've tried using:

```
sort -k3,2
```

However neither of them have worked;

```
sort -k3
```

will sort by the year.

Comment: you should check out `-t` switch to define field separator. Also providing some test case where the sort would be noticeable would be nice.

Comment: Give larger input sample, and expected output.

Comment: So with `sort -t / -k 2,3` it should be working.

Comment: Or just `sort -t / -k 2` or `sort -k 3.7`

Answer (score 2):

`sort -t/ -k 2,3` will tell sort to use the second and third fields, delimited by `/`; I used this expanded input file:

```
$ cat file
Bob, 133454543, 1990/12/10
Alex, 133454543, 1990/12/11
Tom, 234234235, 1992/10/19
Zed, 234234235, 1992/10/18
$ sort -t/ -k 2,3 file
Zed, 234234235, 1992/10/18
Tom, 234234235, 1992/10/19
Bob, 133454543, 1990/12/10
Alex, 133454543, 1990/12/11
```

Note that this ignores the year field for sorting (as implied by the question).